# create a channel with a embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I try to create a very small ticket bot.

I would only like that when reacting a support channel opens and nothing else.

This is the code i am working with.

```
  const ember = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#E40819')
    .setTitle('⚠️SUPPORT')
    .setDescription("Open a Ticket")
    let msgEmbed6 = await message.channel.send(ember)
    await msgEmbed6.react('⚠️')
```

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the `if` statement will only run if the user reacts, I'm not sure what you mean by 'open a support channel'.

```
const reaction = msgEmbed6.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, timeout: TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS });

if (reaction.size > 0) {
    // Creates a new text channel called 'Support'
    const supportChannel = await message.guild.channels.create('Support', { type: 'text' });
    // Stops @everyone from viewing the channel
    await supportChannel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
    // Allows the message author to send messages to the channel
    await supportChannel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
}
```

Comment: what I would like to do is have my bot make a small "private" help channel

Comment: Please see my updated answer and tell me if it's what you wanted

Comment: I did this and put this on the console

https://gyazo.com/d53368c589a527a5cf6e215bcb1a6896
https://gyazo.com/cfb8916d987cebafc6ec52af76c12ed4

Comment: Where I've put TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS you need to put a number there, 1000 been 1 second. That will ensure it's not waiting for a reaction forever.

Comment: the same error in console, TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS is not defined

Comment: Yes, you must replace TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS with a number.

const reaction = msgEmbed6.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, timeout: 15000 });

This would stop waiting for reactions after 15 seconds